# Image animation keeps requesting the images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I test the code in IE7, FF, Chrome, Safari and this problem occurs in Firefox only.

**I have checked that the problem only occurs in FF 3.5.x, but not FF 3.0.x.**

I want to make an image animation which has 10 images in total.

Currently, I use the following code to do it:

```
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    img[i] = new Image();
    img[i].src = "images/survey/share_f"+i+".jpg"
}

var cornerno = 0;
function imganimate(){
     $("#surveyicon").attr("src",img[cornerno].src);
     //some logic to change the cornerno
     setTimeout("imganimate()",1000);
}
```

And then change an element's src to loop through the array "img".

however, firefox keeps requesting the images continuous (I expect it only requests each unique image just once).

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean continuously?  It should load them all consecutively at the time the code is run, but only once per page load unless you have this code inside a click handler or timer callback.  You may want to post more code.

Comment: This problem only occurs in Firefox after testing.

Comment: Question -- 
Why do you never increment cornerno inside the imganimate() function? You'll never move to the next image.

Comment: You may overlook the comment line - "some logic to change the cornerno"

Comment: Wait, why even create the array of images if all you're going to do is set #surveyicon's src attribute to the current image's src attribute? Wouldn't it make more sense to set two variables, one for the path and one for the file extension, instead of assigning putting all the images in an array, and then do `.attr("src", path + i + file_ext)`? Actually, a better idea would be to see if you could somehow set "src" to refer to the actual images in the array and not just be a relative path to files on-server.

Comment: This is a good question, Cat Megex. If I don't create the array of images, this problem will happen in IE too. IE keeps on requesting the server for images. Creating the array can get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a bug in FF3.5.x. 
Not sure whether the bug has already been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You've already created ten DOM nodes, set their src and loaded the images. Why would you set the src again? You want to rotate those ten nodes in and out now. You can either toggle style.display or remove and insert the nodes.

Here's my suggestion. I'm not well versed in JQuery so there may be a few additional shortcuts I've overlooked:

```
var imgAmt = 10;
img = [];
for (var i=1;i<=imgAmt;i++){
    img[i] = document.createElement("img");
    img[i].src = "images/survey/share_f"+i+".jpg"
    img[i].style.display = "none";
    $("#surveyicon").appendChild(img[i]);
}
imganimate();

var cornerno = 0;
function imganimate(){
    cornerno++;
    cornerno = cornerno > imgAmt ? 1 : cornerno;
    for (var i=1;i<=imgAmt;i++){
        // hide all images but the index that matches cornerno:
        img[i].style.display = i==cornerno ? "" : "none";
    }
    setTimeout(imganimate,1000);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is good for me to use this code. I have done some logic on the #surveyicon node.
I have just discovered that the problem occurs in FF 3.5.x only.

Answer (score 0):

img is undefined. just add a line "var img = new Array();" before "for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){"

```
var img = new Array();

for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    img[i] = new Image();
    img[i].src = "images/survey/share_f"+i+".jpg";

}

var cornerno = 0;
function imganimate(){
    cornerno %= 10;
    cornerno++;
     $("#surveyicon").attr("src",img[cornerno].src);

     setTimeout("imganimate()",1000);
}

imganimate();
```

Comment: The code I post is just part of the code. The problem is for the strange behavior of firefox.

Comment: Also, it is better to use var img = [] to declare an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try composing the images into a single image file like a sprite map and then use CSS positioning to shift the image around as a background image. It will be much faster and avoid any reloads.